# ansible task doesn't resolve variable

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts

I'm trying to get VG_Name using below code. I can see variable value using `debug:var` but it doesn't work inside actual task & print value as `"vg": "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg"`

```
 tasks:
   - set_fact:
       LV_name: "opt"
    - name: Get VG Name
      set_fact:
        vg_command: "{{ 'hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.'+ LV_name +'.vg' }}"

    - name: Show VG
      debug:
        var: "{{ vg_command }}"

    - name: extend logical volume and file system
      community.general.lvol:
       vg: "{{ vg_command }}"
       lv: "{{ LV_name }}"
       size: +100%FREE
       resizefs: yes
```

Output:

```
TASK [Get VG Name] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/ansible_disk/disk_extend.yml:92
ok: [SERVER-NAME] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "vg_command": "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Show VG] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/ansible_disk/disk_extend.yml:96
ok: [SERVER-NAME] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg": "vg_00"
}
TASK [extend logical volume and file system] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/ansible_disk/disk_extend.yml:109
fatal: [SERVER-NAME]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "err": "  Volume group name \"hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg\" has invalid characters.\n  Cannot process volume group hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg\n",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "active": true,
            "force": false,
            "lv": "varlog",
            "opts": null,
            "pvs": null,
            "resizefs": true,
            "shrink": true,
            "size": "+100%FREE",
            "snapshot": null,
            "state": "present",
            "thinpool": null,
            "vg": "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Volume group hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.varlog.vg does not exist.",
    "rc": 5
}
```

Tried all possible ways(lookup, vars etc) that I could think of but no luck, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building your string incoorectly, leaving `inventory[hostname]` inside the single quotes, it will be treated as a literal; so:

```
 vg_command: "{{ 'hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs.'+ LV_name +'.vg' }}"
```

should instead be:

```
 vg_command: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs[LV_name].vg }}"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it doesn't read variable name `LV_name`.
& gives error: ```"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs[LV_name].vg }}"```

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly the code you changed, and the full error?

Comment: Tried:
`ansible_lvm.lvs[LV_name].vg` , `ansible_lvm.lvs.[LV_name].vg` & `ansible_lvm.lvs.LV_name.vg`
Is there any way to read variable inside variable.

Comment: The first is the correct way (exactly as it works for `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` for instance, but please, update the question it is a pain to debug in comments

Comment: sorry I was being too impatient, it worked fine like you said!! 
`vg_command: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lvm.lvs[LV_name].vg }}"`